# Windows MySQL console issue

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

I got this error in MySQL Log. What does it mean?

```
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] InnoDB: `enter code here`Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.17 started; log sequence number 1626223
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [ERROR] Aborting

2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Binlog end
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2015-05-05 14:31:41 2620 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2015-05-05 14:31:43 2620 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1626233
2015-05-05 14:31:43 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2015-05-05 14:31:43 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2015-05-05 14:31:43 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2015-05-05 14:31:43 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2015-05-05 14:31:43 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2015-05-05 14:31:43 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2015-05-05 14:31:43 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2015-05-05 14:31:43 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2015-05-05 14:31:43 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2015-05-05 14:31:43 2620 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2015-05-05 14:31:43 2620 [Note] wampmysqld: Arrêt du serveur terminé
```

I followed the fix provided here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.0/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html

But it doesnt work for me. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Its just a guess but these lines from the error log make me think you have another MySQL server running on your PC and it has already grabbed port 3306.

```
[ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
[ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
```

Look in the Services snapin

```
windows key + R
Keyin services.msc
Press OK button
```

WAMPServer's MySQL Server instance is called `wampmysqld` or `wampmysqld64` if you installed 64bit WAMPServer.

If another MySQL instance is running it is probably called `MYSQL`. If you see one of those you already have a MySQL Server running.

> Work out why.
>
> If you no longer need that other instance, uninstall it.
>
> Remember to backup any databases you think you may still need to move to WAMPServer's MySQL Server.

You definitely only need one MySQL on your PC.

Alternatively you could change the `Startup Type` of the MYSQL Service to Disabled. Then you can go back and re-enable it if you later find you needed it for something.

Disabling the other service will allow WAMPServer's MySQL to startup.